# ¿Cómo corregir este error cuando robots.txt no es válido?

Tags: javascript, seo

Me sale este error cuando reviso la pagina donde dice robots.txt no es válido 1758 errores encontrados la verdad no se que hacer

Pero en la  pagina si tengo eso.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en el head yo si tengo digo requerimiento

```
<html lang="es">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- <base href="vista/"> -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Además me muestra errores con el document.getElementById().value. que son usados par obtener datos de un input o cualquier div.  Esta revisión del sitio la estoy haciendo en https://pagespeed.web.dev   donde se puede observar el rendimiento del sitio no se que tan real sea referente a lo que pide google.

Comment: Ese análisis básicamente no entendió nada de tu documento HTML. Lo raro es que el HTML que incluyes en tu pregunta no tiene el DOCTYPE... estás seguro que estás analizando la URL correcta?

Comment: `robots.txt` es un archivo de texto, no html https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt

Comment: Pues, si uno prueba sobre https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fyolutronica.com%2F no se ve nada de lo que muestras en la captura. Necesitas aclarar CÓMO estás revisando la página en pagespeed con más detalle, sobre cuál URL, etc. No es evidente lo que estás intentando ;) Ve a [edit] la pregunta y mejórala, por favor

Comment: Cuando le das revisar y le das en el SEO abajito te aparece el error.

Answer (score 0):

No se ve por ninguna parte cómo estás definiendo el robots.txt.

Como te indicaron en el comentario, es un archivo plano con un formato acorde al estándar [RFC 9309](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9309.html).

Comienza siendo algo así:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/

User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Luego, puedes añadir instrucciones de allow, deny y otras políticas por las que le indicas a los crawlers qué deben o no deben indizar para los resultados de búsqueda.

Entonces, si en la configuración de tu sitio, del proxy, del nginx o del que sea que configuraste, tienes el robots.txt apuntando a un documento html, vas a tener muchos problemas porque eso no cumple el estándar antes mencionado.

Crea el archivo, lo pones en la raíz del sitio y comienza a definir las políticas de indizado para los crawlers. Usa la guía que te compartieron en el comentario: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/create-robots-txt